# How to connect 5 colored wire headphone to 3.5 TRS jack?

Tags: audio, headphones, audio-codec, trs

I have a somictone headphone and I want to repair its headphone jack, It contains five colored wires.
Here are the wire and TRS jack.
Please give me a feedback

[image]

[image]

Can you please tell me how to wire this?
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: what is at the other end of each wire? ... connect it the same way as the old jack

Comment: If you buy 100 of these headphones and cut the plugs off them, you will likely find several different wiring colour schemes, sometimes even in the same batch.

Comment: typical red and green are used for stereo left n right. you may "stimulate" them by a low voltage like from a 1,5V battery or an ohm-meter to hear which is which. the gnd is normally the outer layer of the wire, the signal is in the core (be careful when dismanteling), how to connect the 3,5mm jack, there are plenty of sides which show how to: e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)  , go to german for some better tables and schematics :-), Also with headphone wires you normaly need to burn away the conformal coating with the soldering tip